# Printing string if the value is null or not present

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do, is basically, if I scrape a name database, I'll print out the values based on conditions I define in the code below. But if the value is null (in my case not present), I'd like to print "-" on my page for this value. What is happening now, I get "null" shown in my HTML template for the values, which are not present. Seems like an easy thing, but somehow it's not working.

```
 let nameHTML = ""
  if ((data.name.first && data.name.last) || (data.name.third && data.name.fourth)) {
    nameHTML = `
      <div class="name">
        <p class="black">${data.name.first} ${data.name.last}, ${data.name.third} ${data.name.fourth} </p>
      </div>
    `
  } else {
    nameHTML = `
      <div class="name">
        <p class="black">${data.name.first = "-"} ${data.name.last = "-"}, ${data.name.third = "-"} ${data.name.fourth = "-"} </p>
      </div>
    `
  }
```

Comment: is it supposed to be `data.name.first && data.address.last` ... or `data.name.first && data.second.last`?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a default value with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) for [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. This replaces empty strings `''` as well.

```
let nameHTML = `
      <div class="name">
        <p class="black">${data.name.first || '-'} ${data.name.last || '-'}, ${data.name.third || '-'} ${data.name.fourth || '-'} </p>
      </div>
    `;
```